# Bitnami RedmineにてRedmine_Bannerを導入するとInternal Error(505)が表示され使用不可になりました

Tags: redmine

Windows7にてBitnami Redmineを使用しているのですが、Redmine_Bunnerを導入した直後からInternal Errorが表示され、Redmineが使用できなくなってしまいました。Redmine_Bunnerが使用できなくても構わないので、Redmineを復元する方法を教えていただけないでしょうか。

## 導入環境

- Windows7(32bit)
- Bitnami Redmine 3.4.4.stable

## 実施手順

下記エントリに記載させていただきました。
[Bitnami RedmineにRedmineBannerを導入したかった - Qiita](https://qiita.com/asakura_0603/items/0571229b5c920c31b585)

## 発生現象

localhost/Redmineにアクセスすると、トップページが表示されず、"Redmine 500 error"というタイトルで下記エラーメッセージが表示されておりました。

```
Internal error

An error occurred on the page you were trying to access.
If you continue to experience problems please contact your Redmine administrator for assistance.

If you are the Redmine administrator, check your log files for details about the error.
```

エラーログは下記のとおりです。

```
Started GET "/redmine/" for XXX.X.X.X at 2018-XX-XX XX:XX:XX +0900
Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
  Current user: **** (id=1)
  Rendered welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/base (2.0ms)
Missing template, responding with 404
  Rendered common/error.html.erb within layouts/base (0.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 427ms (ActiveRecord: 236.0ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial banner/_project_body_bottom with {:locale=>[:ja, :en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :rsb]}. Searched in:
  * "C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.4.4-3/apps/redmine/htdocs/plugins/redmine_work_time/app/views"
  * "C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.4.4-3/apps/redmine/htdocs/plugins/easy_gantt/app/views"
  * "C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.4.4-3/apps/redmine/htdocs/app/views"
  * "C:/Bitnami/redmine-3.4.4-3/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/redmine_extensions-0.2.9/app/views"
):
    105:         
    106:     
    107: 
    108:     
    109:         
    110:         
    111:         
  plugins/redmine_banner-master/lib/banner_application_hooks.rb:17:in `view_layouts_base_content'
  lib/redmine/hook.rb:61:in `block (2 levels) in call_hook'
  lib/redmine/hook.rb:61:in `each'
  lib/redmine/hook.rb:61:in `block in call_hook'
  lib/redmine/hook.rb:58:in `tap'
  lib/redmine/hook.rb:58:in `call_hook'
  lib/redmine/hook.rb:96:in `call_hook'
  app/views/layouts/base.html.erb:108:in `_app_views_layouts_base_html_erb___215493345_35494368'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:491:in `block (2 levels) in render_error'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:489:in `render_error'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:477:in `render_404'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:501:in `missing_template'
```

Answer (score 1):

こちらcentOS6.9ですが...

- Redmine version      3.4.6.stable
- redmine_banner         0.1.2

同様にInternal errorとなり、ログも"Missing template, responding with 404"でほぼ同じです。
pluginsディレクトリに解凍したplugin名は "redmine_banner-master"でしょうか。
当方はzip解凍したときに"redmine_banner-master"ができたためそのままインストールして症状が発生していました。
アンインストール後、"redmine_banner"にリネームして再インストールすることで無事Redmine Banner pluginが利用できるようになりました。

参考になれば幸いです

Answer (score 0):

[Readme](https://github.com/akiko-pusu/redmine_banner/blob/master/README.md)に書いてる Unstall を実行してはいかがでしょうか。
事前にOSバックアップを取ることをオススメします。

> Uninstall
>
> For Redmine 2.x, use the following command:
>
> ```
> rake redmine:plugins:migrate NAME=redmine_banner VERSION=0 RAILS_ENV=production
> ```
>
> For Redmine 1.x, use the following command:
>
> ```
> rake db:migrate_plugins NAME=redmine_banner VERSION=0 RAILS_ENV=production
> ```